# How to Auto logout the user when JSON Web Token Expires?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, jwt

I want to logout the user as soon as the token expires. So in a sign-in code I am using setTimeout to logout the user.

```
function signIn () {
// Successfull SignIN
setTimeout( logout, expiryTime ) 
}
```

Problem I am facing is the timeout function is cleared when user reload any screen when signed-in.

I can't use interceptors and token is not auto-refreshing, the only option I have is to get the expiry-time when user sign-in. Is there any way to persist the setTimeout even on windows reload or some other way to logout if we only have to work with expiry-time value on sign-in.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

If your routes are already properly protected, does it really matter if the UI reflects that a user is signed in despite the JWT being expired?

If the JWT is expired and the user tries to access a protected page, you can issue a 401 response and redirect the user to the login page.